# using cursor attributes in a CURSOR FOR LOOP

Tags: oracle, loops, for-loop, plsql, cursor

I am running the following in the Scott schema:

```
SET serveroutput ON;

BEGIN
FOR c_Emp IN (SELECT * FROM emp)
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line('The record processed by the cursor ' || c_Emp%rowcount);
END LOOP;
end;
```

This gives the error:

cursor attribute may not be applied to non-cursor 'C_EMP'

However if this is done using an explicit cursor it works fine:

set serveroutput on ;

```
DECLARE 
       emp_record emp%ROWTYPE; 
       count_variable NUMBER;
       CURSOR c IS 
SELECT * FROM emp;
BEGIN
OPEN c;
loop
fetch  c INTO emp_record;
exit WHEN c%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line ('The record count is   ' || c%rowcount);
END loop;
close c;
end;
```

Just want to understand : whether while using the CURSOR FOR LOOP, is the index variable not a cursor attribute, if so why? could someone plz expalin this....

Comment: Why not let us know what you are doing on what system and what language?

Comment: I [guess](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SCOTT) you are referring to SQL on an Oracle DBMS. Correct?

Comment: Apologies if this is not clear, It is an Oracle RDBMS and I am executing this PL/SQL block on Scott schema.

Answer (score 1):

`c_Emp` is not the cursor, its a record with felds for each column in the SELECT statment

`c_Emp`  is similar to the `emp_record` from your second example.

Comment: So is there any way to access the cursor attributes if a Cursor For loop is used?

Comment: in plsql you can access the attributes of an implicit CURSOR using `SQL`- prefix e.g. `SQL%ROWCOUNT`. But i'm not sure if that will work in a FOR loop. [see docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/sql_cursor.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Even while using a FOR loop the cursor has to be explicitly defined. 
A sample use of FOR loop with a cursor would look like below:

```
declare
 cursor c1 is select a from table;
begin
 FOR b in c1
 loop
  <required logic>
 end loop;
end;
```

Comment: using just a select clause, I can define an implicit cursor in the For loop, if I define the cursor explicitly I think it falls under the second case.    I searched in the doc, got to know that for an implicity defined cursors like this, the cursor attribute will be NULL, so using SQL%ROWCOUNT gives a NULL value.

Comment: Try what Baljeet suggests.  It works.  Replace his <required logic> with "dbms_output.put_line ('The record count is   ' || c1%rowcount);" and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

To get the index in a for loop, you can add the ***rownum*** pseudocolumn in the select clause of implicit cursor.

```
SET serveroutput ON;

BEGIN
  FOR c_Emp IN (SELECT e.*, rownum FROM emp e)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('The record processed by the cursor ' || c_Emp.rownum);
  END LOOP;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET serveroutput ON;

DECLARE
x NUMBER :=0 ;
BEGIN
FOR c_Emp IN (SELECT * FROM emp)
LOOP
x := x+1;
dbms_output.put_line('The record processed by the cursor ' || x);
END LOOP;
-----
IF x>0 THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Cursr was opened');
ELSE
dbms_output.put_line('Cursr was not opened');
END IF; 

end;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31569407)

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> create table product(
  2     product_id number(4)     not null,
  3     product_description varchar2(20) not null
  4  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into product values (1,'Java');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into product values (2,'Oracle');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into product values (3,'C#');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into product values (4,'Javascript');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into product values (5,'Python');

1 row created.


SQL> create table company(
  2     product_id        number(4)    not null,
  3     company_id          NUMBER(8)    not null,
  4     company_short_name  varchar2(30) not null,
  5     company_long_name   varchar2(60)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into company values(1,1001,'A Inc.','Long Name A Inc.');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into company values(1,1002,'B Inc.','Long Name B Inc.');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into company values(1,1003,'C Inc.','Long Name C Inc.');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into company values(2,1004,'D Inc.','Long Name D Inc.');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into company values(2,1005,'E Inc.','Long Name E Inc.');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into company values(2,1006,'F Inc.','Long Name F Inc.');

1 row created.


SQL> DECLARE
  2    CURSOR cursorValue IS
  3      SELECT h.product_description,o.company_short_name FROM company o,product h
  4      WHERE o.product_id =h.product_id
  5      ORDER by 2;
  6    num_total_rows NUMBER;
  7  BEGIN
  8
  9    FOR idx IN cursorValue LOOP
 10      dbms_output.put_line(rpad(idx.product_description,20,' ')||' '||
 11      rpad(idx.company_short_name,30,' '));
 12
 13      num_total_rows :=cursorValue%ROWCOUNT;
 14    END LOOP;
 15    IF num_total_rows >0 THEN
 16      dbms_output.new_line;
 17      dbms_output.put_line('Total Organizations = '||to_char(num_total_rows));
 18    END IF;
 19  END;
 20  /
Java                 A Inc.
Java                 B Inc.
Java                 C Inc.
Oracle               D Inc.
Oracle               E Inc.
Oracle               F Inc.
Total Organizations = 6

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


SQL> drop table product;

Table dropped.


SQL> drop table company;

Table dropped.

    enter code here
```

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, it doesn't address the question the OP was asking almost 9 years ago. The OP was asking trying to understand a concept, you are providing a piece of code without context and without providing information about the concept the OP was trying to understand